# How can i pretty print a json in my angular html file?

Tags: angular

I am displaying a json object in my angular html view. i would like to pretty print it . This is how it is displayed currently.

[image]

I would like to replace all \ characters and print it in a cleaner way. really appreciate if you can help.

currently in my html template . i am displaying it with a json pipe.

```
  <pre> {{ item['auditData'] | json }} </pre>
```

How can i display the json in a cleaner way. I would like to expect it to be displayed something like the below

```
{
  "queryParams": {
    "traffic_type": "CAMPAIGN",
    "start_date": "2021-07-31T23:00:00Z",
    "end_date": "2021-08-17T23:00:00Z",
    "primecast_account_name": "Test Account",
    "page_number": 0,
    "page_size": 10
  }
}
```

the following is my original string.

```
{ "queryParams": "{\n \"traffic_type\" : \"CAMPAIGN\",\n \"start_date\" : \"2021-07-31T23:00:00Z\",\n \"end_date\" : \"2021-08-17T23:00:00Z\",\n \"primecast_account_name\" : \"Test Account\",\n \"page_number\" : 0,\n \"page_size\" : 10\n}" }
```

really appreciate if you can help me .

Comment: Why does your string include `\n`'s? This basically makes it not-json. Get rid of them and try your pipe again

Comment: it was using faster xml object mapper to convert an object and it was written into cassandra . maybe cassandra specific libaries would have added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and it works well now.

```
        {{ 'LABELS.AUDIT.FLIGHT.FLIGHT_SUBMITTED_CAMPAIGN_MGR_APPROVAL' | translate: { campaignName : item['auditData']['CAMPAIGN_NAME'], flightName:  item['auditData']['FLIGHT_NAME'] }  }}
```

it printed very nicely.

[image]